# Quem executa primeiro em Python a condição ou o bloco de código?

Tags: python, condição

Gente estou com um problema e eu acredito que seja por causa da ordem de execução eu não posso rodar tal bloco de código se ele não passar primeiro por uma condição se não vai dar erro, e uma vez ouvir falar que em C ele primeiro executa o código depois verifica, isso é verdade? E como é em python?

```
 menor = 9999999999999999999999999999
    valor_k = 0
    for k in range(self.numero_vertices): 
        if (grafo.number_of_edges(v,k) == 1): # se for diferente de 1 não deveria fazer nada so aumentar o valor de k no for
            if (grafo[v][k]['tamanho'] < menor and self.verifica_fonte(grafo, k, v) == True):
                menor = self.grafo[v][k]['tamanho']
                valor_k = k
    return valor_k
```

Comment: Depende do que está falando, mostre o código e o que acha que é primeiro.

Comment: Editei a pergunta e coloquei o código

Comment: O que você não entende? O que acha que executa primeiro?

Comment: Quando ele chega na minha primeira condição estou achando que ele não verifica ela mas sim faz o restante do código depois volta nela para verificar se realmente minha função retornou 1 ou não. Ouvi falar uma vez que na linguagem C ele fazia isso por ser mais "econômico". Gostaria de saber se isso é verdade e se em python também é assim.

Comment: Explique melhor o que você ouviu falar. Não parece ser procedente nada disso, inclusive por que seria incoerente.

Comment: Acho que realmente deve ser algo no meu código que está errado, também estava achando que não fosse isso, mas perguntei para ter certeza, de qualquer forma agradeço sua ajuda. Vou sentar aqui e vê onde estou errando, Obrigado.

Comment: Depois de muito tentar descobri que o erro, era que eu esta esquecendo de atribuir um valor a uma variavel no construtor da minha classe. huhuehueheu, já estava achando que era erro de outro mundo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ele primeiro executa o código depois verifica

Isso não é verdade, acredito que pra nenhuma linguagem.

```
if 1 > 2:
    print('Isso nunca vai ser executado.')
```

No exemplo acima, o `print` não vai ser executado.

Se o código dentro do seu `if` está sendo executado quando não deveria, é porque a condição avaliada por ele resultou em `True`. Sugiro que use um debugger ou `print` nas suas variáveis pra entender o que está acontecendo e onde está a suposição errada.

Quanto ao que você ouviu, provavelmente entendeu mal o seguinte:

---

O que pode acontecer é que talvez você verifique uma condição de modo que tenha efeitos secundários. Por exemplo:

```
def verificar_xyz():
    print('Isso sempre será executado.')
    return False

if verificar_xyz():
    print('Isso nunca será executado.')
```

Nesse caso, o bloco dentro do `if` não será executado porque `verificar_xyz` retorna `False`, mas o `print` de dentro da função é executado, porque a função é executada normalmente até o `return`.

---

Em um `if` ou outra verificação de condição, se uma das condições em um `and` é negativa, a avaliação pára imediatamente. Isso quer dizer que, por exemplo, os seguintes trechos se comportam de modo diferente:

```
if verificar_xyz() and 1 > 2:
    print('Isso nunca será executado.')
```

Aqui o bloco dentro do `if` não será executado, mas a função `verificar_xyz` foi executada e o texto "Isso sempre será executado" de dentro da função é mostrado na tela. `1 > 2` não chega a ser avaliado porque a primeira condição avaliada já retornou `False`.

```
if 1 > 2 and verificar_xyz():
    print('Isso nunca será executado.')
```

Aqui o "Isso sempre será executado" da função `verificar_xyz` *não* será executado porque já que `1 > 2` resulta em `False`, o Python (ou outra linguagem) sabe que a condição `and` não pode ser verdadeira e imediatamente pula o bloco, sem avaliar `verificar_xyz()`.

Por isso, é recomendável que as funções usadas em avaliações de condição não tenham efeitos secundários. Isso pode gerar bugs sutis.